# Adding applications to dock through terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm managing multiple computers and want to send out a script that will run in terminal that will add certain applications to the dock.  The code I am trying is

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict>    <key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Macintosh HD/Applications/Google Chrome.app/</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'
killall Dock;
```

I have also tried

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/Google Chrome.app/</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'
killall Dock;
```

with and without spaces in between Google Chrome.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm running Mavericks and this worked for me:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>/Applications/Google Chrome.app</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'

killall Dock
```